# Jinja2 template inheritance based on language

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, jinja2

I'm working on a python GAE (with jijna2) project. The idea is to make templates inherit themselves based on my request internationalization values.
For example I have a template directory tree:

```
templates
---- base.html
---- site_nav.html
---- CA
-------- site_nav.html
-------- fr
------------ site_nav.html
```

Now when a Canada/French user requests a template i want Jijna2 to look for it in the `templates/CA/fr` directory if none found look in `templates/CA` if none in `templates` then eventualy raise an `TemplateDoesNotExist`. The deeper templates like `templates/CA/fr/site_nav.html` would have only:

```
{% extends site_nav.html %} # to extend the templates/CA/site_nav.html
{% block logged_in %}
    Canadian French content
{% endblock logged_in %}
```

As the `templates/CA/site_nav.html` isn't existing we extend from `templates/site_nav.html` which contains:

```
{% block logged_in %}
    American content
{% endblock logged_in %}
```

I want to include it from anywhere by using `{% include 'site_nav.html' %}` and have proper (deeper) template loaded if my nationality need it.

This is just a solution I got up in the moment. I am aware that this can be impossible especially the `{% extends site_nav.html %}` that should never try to extend itself but eventually the parent one.

This is just an example I'm hoping that there is a good and Pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: Why not to use i18n module? http://mikeshilkov.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/enable-jinja2-and-i18n-translations-on-google-appengine/

Answer (score 0):

When you use a Jinja function loader you can control how templates are loaded.

Docs: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#loaders

Example: I use a function loader to load every template from the datastore and create child templates for content blocks in the base template. A function loader can also read the templates in your project (path).